# Is it possible to run a Windows 2003 x86 Virtual PC created by VMWare on Windows 7 64 bits?

Tags: vmware-player

Is it possible to run a Windows 2003 x86 Virtual PC created by VMWare on Windows 7 64 bits?

Comment: Which VMware product is installed on the Windows 7 x64 machine?

Comment: I have installed the VMPlayer

Answer (score 1):

With a properly installed and functioning VMware Player, you should be fine.